# convert the output from jq to array

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I have dynamodb table present in the aws account, I want to filter it based on the certain conditioning and get the result as an array

below is the aws cli query with jq

```
aws dynamodb scan  --table-name sample-table  | jq .Items | jq 'map(select(.VpcId.S != "None")) ' | jq  .[].VpcId.S
```

here is the output which I am getting:

```
"vpc-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
"vpc-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
"vpc-XXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx"
```

I want the output as

```
[
"vpc-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
"vpc-zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
"vpc-XXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxx"
]
```

so that I can pass it to the terraform.

below is the output of the actual command

```
aws dynamodb scan  --table-name sample-table

{
"Items": [
  {
   
    "VpcId": {
      "S": "vpc-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    }
  },
    {
   
    "VpcId": {
      "S": "None"
    }
  },
  {
   
    "VpcId": {
      "S": "vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  },
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `.[].VpcId.S` with `map(.VpcId.S)`. The `.[]` syntax takes the elements out of the array.

---

You can combine your different `jq` filters together in this way:

```
.Items | map(select(.VpcId.S != "None") | .VpcId.S)
```